# Django change the admin page label 'Auth' to 'Authentication'

Tags: django, django-admin

How can i change the display label `Auth` in the Django admin dashboard to `Authentication`?

Comment: technically, the models in the `django.contrib.auth` are used for both authentication **and** authorization, so naming it "Authentication" would be kind of misleading ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no easy/elegant way to do this. Customisable app-labelling has been a sore point for some time. You can [override](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) `admin/index.html` and inject some javascript code to change the labelling. Note that you could also change `admin.site.index_template` to something like `"admin/my_index.html"`, which can then use `{% extends "admin/index.html" %}` to keep things DRYer.

Of course there are other areas in the admin that "Auth" will appear also, such in `"admin/app_index.html"`, the breadcrumbs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if your overwriting admin/index.html you could hard code the logic in the template instead of any javascript:

```
<caption><a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section">
        {% ifequal app.name "Auth" %}
                {% trans 'Authentication' %}
        {% else %}
                {% blocktrans with app.name as name %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endifequal %}
</a></caption>
```